# how to transfer a website between two host

Tags: linux, ftp, hosting, host

i want to change my website host(linux) and I need to transfer flies from my old host to the new one I've zipped my site content into a backup file and now I want to upload this file to my new host how can I do that?

PS:
I have tried this solution but I got 504 time-out error:

```
 file_put_contents('backup.tar.gz', file_get_contents('http://hiva.com:2082/cpsess5550968018/download?skipencode=1&file=%2fhome%2fhivarobotics%2fpublic_ftp%2fbackup.tar.gz'));
```

TNX:)

Comment: `rsync` would be preferrable tool for that

Answer (score 1):

You can do this securely with ssh copy:

```
scp -r /my_old_website_folder username@my_new_host:/my_new_website_folder
```

All you need is an ssh login.